# How can I find/detect global state in a project?

Tags: c++, c

I've got a very large project (which I didn't write). From the code I've looked through, I can't find any global state in the project, but my coworker has told me there is global state in the project (which is why we can only create one context session in a process, instead of creating multiple context sessions in a singe process). So now I'm wondering where this global state is in the code base.

Now, of course, I could ask him about where the global state is. But I figured I'd come to StackOverflow and see if there's a better alternative (i.e. one that doesn't require me taking time my coworker doesn't have, and something I can do on (future) projects when the original maintainers of the code aren't accessible for me to ask questions). If there's global state in a program/library, how can I find/detect it?

(note: I've tagged this both C and C++ because these projects are both C and C++ based)

Comment: There is not much you can do but read and understand the sourcecode. You need to get an overview without going too much into details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 to Lundin for mentioning system resources that might have global state but not show up when looking for global variables. But since detecting that automatically is nigh impossible, I've focused on doing just global variables. This is what I've been using on OS X and Linux:

```
nm ./file | egrep ' [dD] '
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat global.cpp 
#include <iostream>

int global_external = 1; // Should show up
static int global_static = 2; // Should show up
namespace
{
int global_anon = 3; // Should show up
}

void foo()
{
    static int static_local = 4; // Should show up
    int local = 5;  // Should NOT show up

    std::cout << global_external << std::endl;
    std::cout << global_static << std::endl;
    std::cout << global_anon << std::endl;
    std::cout << static_local << std::endl;
    std::cout << local << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

---

```
$ c++ global.cpp -o program
```

---

```
$ nm program | egrep ' [dD] '
0000000100001078 d __ZL13global_static
000000010000107c d __ZN12_GLOBAL__N_111global_anonE
0000000100001074 d __ZZ3foovE12static_local
0000000100001070 D _global_external
```

As can be seen, only the globals are printed. It's even clearer with C, due to less name mangling.

Comment: Unless a better answer comes along, I'm going to accept this solution I found.

Answer (score 2):

"Global", as in global variable, is perhaps not the whole truth of it. But rather you are probably looking for something which is only allocated once ("singleton"). In the case of variables, all variables that are allocated at file scope (outside functions) or as static have this attribute. (They also have *static storage duration*.) So in case this "state" you are looking for is stored in a variable, go look for variables allocated at file scope or as static.

It is of course also possible that the program uses some external resource, which is only allocated once, such as a file, a hardware resource or a Windows register key etc. In that case it turns more complex and there's no generic way to find out.